# Finding all quadratic residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $p$ is an odd prime. $a$ is a primitive root mod $p$.
>   Prove that the quadratic residues mod $p$ are $a^{2i}$  when $0 \leq i \leq (p-1)/2$.

What I know is that $a^{2i}$ are always quadratic residues, because there is $x=a^i$ such that $x^2=a^{2i}$.
But I don't know how can I show that they are the only.

Thanks.

Comment: **Hint:** Try counting them. Remember - there are two roots for every square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
If $a$ is a primitive root of $p$, then $a$ can not be a residue, otherwise there will be an element of order =$2(p-1)$, impossible. So all odd powers of $a$ are not residues, and are there any other elements than what we have considered?

Thanks and regards, barring mistakes.

Comment: why "So all odd powers of a are not residues"?

Comment: Because odd powers of $a$ are products of $a$ and an even power of $a$, that is, a product of residue and non-residue, so is a non-residue still. Hope this helps in clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be a primitive root.

The even powers of $a$ are, as you observed, quadratic residues. Since the $2i$ are $\le p-1$,  the $a^{2i}$ are all incongruent modulo $p$.

There are $\dfrac{p-1}{2}$ of them, so they must be **all** the quadratic residues.

The odd powers must therefore be the quadratic non-residues.