# Why is the square of any odd number $n$, $7 \nmid n$, always congruent to either $1, 2$ or $4$ ($\operatorname{mod} 7$)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have seen the proof for why all odd perfect squares are congruent to $1 \operatorname{mod} 8$, but how can this be applied to an odd modulus like $\operatorname{mod} 7$?

Comment: Even squares are also $0, 1, 2, $ or $4\pmod7$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all quadratic residues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344978/finding-all-quadratic-residues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Well $1,2,4$ are the only quadratic residues $\pmod{7}$.
- Any number when divided by $7$ has remainders $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$. Note that $$0^{2},1^{2},2^{2},3^{2},4^{2},5^{2},6^{2}$$ all have remainders either $0,1,2,4$ $\pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=2k+1$, $n^2=4k^2+4k+1$. You know that $k \neq 3 (\mbox{ mod } 7)$.

Now observe the different values that $4k^2+4k+1$ takes for $k=0,1,2,4,5,6$. They are exactly $1,2,4$ modulo 7.

Answer (score 1):

If $7\nmid n,$ then, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $7\mid n^6-1,$

so $7\mid n^6-7n^4+14n^2-8=(n^2-1)(n^2-2)(n^2-4)$.

Comment: Simpler: $\bmod 7\!:\ n\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow, n\equiv \pm1,\pm2,\pm3\,\Rightarrow\, n^2\equiv 1,4,2\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

For any $p\gt2$, there are $(p-1)/2$ nonzero squares mod $p$.  For $p\gt3$, the sum of the nonzero squares is divisible by $p$ (since $1^2+2^2+\cdots+(p-1)^2=(p-1)p(2p-1)/6$).  Among the nonzero squares are $1$ and $4$. So for $p=7$ there is one more nonzero square, $r$, and we must have $7\mid(1+4+r)$.  The only possibility is $r=2$.